# Qwik attribute "q:slot" becames "q: slot" after formatting in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsx, qwik

I'm developing Qwik app in VSCode, there are some special Qwik attributes, for example: `q:slot` and `bind:value`. However, when I do format, the editor auto add space after colon, so they become: `q: slot` and `bind: value`.

My question is, is there any setting to ignore format attributes like that? I'm currently using the default *TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features*

When I have a code like this, and I format with the default *TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features*

```html
<div q:slot="heading">
{heading}
</div>
```

However, the editor splits `q:` and `slot` so the code became:

```html
<div q: slot="heading">
{heading}
</div>
```

It should not split `q:` and `slot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue is really similar to this one
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6284

I tried many *TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features* configurations without any success. e.g. disable all
javascript.format.insertSpace* and
typescript.format.insertSpaceA* configs

Btw you can use prettier because it's so good https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Comment: Ahh, tried prettier but no luck, the problem came from latest VSCode with prettier here.

https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/3020

Comment: it's strange because, I have VSCode Version: 1.79.0 and Prettier v9.13.0 and it's working fine